# Eliminar archivos sin dejar rastro en commits en Subversion

Tags: subversion, svn

Algunos archivos se subieron por error a mi repositorio y me gustaría saber si existe algún método para eliminarlos por completo ya que si los borro y hago commit sigue quedando el histórico de que alguna vez estuvieron allí.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aparentemente sí se puede hacer, pero no es trivial. Está explicado en [este documento (en inglés)](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal).

Hay un "issue" para poder tener un comando `svnadmin obliterate` pero aún no se soporta.

La forma de hacerlo por ahora es (traducción libre del link anterior):

> Mientras tanto, la única forma de hacerlo es mediante un `svnadmin dump` del repositorio, filtrar el resultado mediante `svndumpfilter` (excluyendo el path que se quiere borrar) y luego un `svnadmin load`. Hay más detalles en el [capítulo 5 del libro de Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.html).

Answer (score 3):

Por el momento no es posible. Existe un [*feature request*](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=516&historysort=new) para crear el comando `svn obliterate` que en teoría serviría para lo que necesitas, pero lamentablemente el issue lleva mucho tiempo abierto y no parecen haber nuevas noticias sobre esto.

Sin embargo existe la posibilidad de manipular directamente los dumps para lograr algo parecido.

Usando `svnadmin` y `svndumpfilter`

```
svnadmin dump <nombre-del-repo> | svndumpfilter exclude "<archivo-a-eliminar>"  > <nombre-archivo-backup>
```

Luego se crea el nuevo repositorio y se importa el dump de la siguiente forma:

```
svnadmin load <nombre-del-repo><nombre-archivo-backup>
```